# Bootstrap jumbotron background image won't display on Heroku

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My jumbotron background image works perfectly locally, and worked great with Bootstrap 2 when it was a hero unit. Now when I deploy to Heroku I get a blank jumbotron. Here's my CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
height: 400px;
width: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 15px;
background-image: url(ttable.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: black;  
}
```

Did something change with teh switch to Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a fix while Googling. Here is where I found it: http://natashatherobot.com/rails-4-heroku-assets-not-found-css-image/

Change the config.assets.compile in the production.rb file to true like this:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
YOURAPPLICATION::Application.configure do

   # your config settings

   config.assets.compile = true

   # your other config settings
end
```

Comment: This just helped me solve the same issue. Nice and simple.  Thanks.